# Isolate downward-facing faces of a convex hull

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-hulls, triangulation

long time fan / first time poster here!

My question: is there an efficient algorithm for isolating just the downward-facing faces of a 3D convex hull?

In two dimensions, if one draws a line from the rightmost point on the hull to the leftmost point on the hull, that line will definitionally serve to part the upward-facing lines on the hull from the downward-facing lines, i.e. separate the lower hull from the upper hull.

Does anyone know an analogue in 3D?
I know people do this all the time, because the lower hull is used in Delaunay triangulation, and the lower hull is used in thermodynamics, but I haven't been able to track down a description of how to do it in 3D.

Any help or references would be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: This lower hull, in certain cases, has to do with the so called "farthest point Voronoi diagram".

Comment: Could you give me information about "lower hull is used in Delaunay triangulation, and the lower hull is used in thermodynamics" ? Besides, are you interested by my comment about "farthest point Voronoi" ?